# Javascript Regular expression to wrap unquoted JSON Values (NOT keys) with double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, regex, hashmap

I have been trying to wrap some malformed JSON values with double quotes. The response is from a Java Servlet (its actually a hashmap) which I have no control over. I have managed to get it from this:

```
{ response={ type=000, products=[{id=1,name=productone},{id=2,name=producttwo}],status=success}}
```

to this:

```
{"response": { "type": 000, "products": [{"id": 1,"name": productone},{"id": 2,"name": producttwo}],"status": success}}
```

using the following regexes:

```
hashmap  =  hashmap
        .replace (/ /g,"").replace(/\s/g,"")                    //replace all spaces
        .replace (/'/g,"").replace(/"/g,'')                     //replace all quotes
        .replace(/=/g,":")                                      //replace = with :
        .replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');  //put quotes around keys
```

How would I go around wrapping the values with double quotes using a regex. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT :**

I would eventually want it to be in this form :

```
{"response": { "type": "000", "products": [{"id": "1","name": "productone"},{"id": "2","name": "producttwo"}],"status": "success"}}
```

Comment: What is the form you want to get to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to quote all keys and values, as you want:

```
hashmap = hashmap.replace(/ /g, '')                  // strip all spaces
                 .replace(/([\w]+)=/g, '"$1"=')      // quote keys
                 .replace(/=([\w]+)/g, ':"$1"')      // quote values
                 .replace(/=([[{])/g, ':$1');        // = to : before arrays and objects also
```

This produces:

```
{"response":{"type":"000","products":[{"id":"1","name":"productone"},{"id":"2","name":"producttwo"}],"status":"success"}}
```

Now you can convert it to JavaScript object with:

```
obj = JSON.parse(hashmap);
```

However, more in line with JSON parsing would be not to quote numeric values, but rather to parse them as numbers, like this:

```
hashmap = hashmap.replace(/ /g, '')
                 .replace(/([\w]+)=/g, '"$1"=')
                 .replace(/=([a-zA-Z_]+)/g, ':"$1"')
                 .replace(/=([\d]+)/g, function(m, num) {return ':'+parseFloat(num)})
                 .replace(/=([[{])/g, ':$1')
```

This produces:

```
{"response":{"type":0,"products":[{"id":1,"name":"productone"},{"id":2,"name":"producttwo"}],"status":"success"}}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... +1