# How do I parse this non-standard JSON format?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, json5

I want to know some process information ran on the VPS with PM2. But, with the JSON string return by PM2, we can't run `JSON.parse()` because the JSON is broken.

An example of what PM2 returns:

```js
'{data: 0, informations: "hello", name: "test"}'
```

But, if you know how the JSON.parse work, you know the problem.
We can't parse this string.

Do you have idea to resolve this problem with another function ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write your own parser or fix whatever generates that not-JSON string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Regular expression to wrap unquoted JSON Values (NOT keys) with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099150/javascript-regular-expression-to-wrap-unquoted-json-values-not-keys-with-doubl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your specific non-json format. The trick is to make sure to have double quotes around keys...

```js
function customParse(string){
  return JSON.parse(string
                    .replace(/\s|"/g, '')        // Removes all spaces and double quotes
                    .replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"') // Adds double quotes everywhere
                    .replace(/"(\d+)"/g, '$1')   // Removes double quotes around integers
                   )
}

// Testing the function
let PM2_string = '{data: 0, informations: "hello", name: "test"}'
let PM2_obj = customParse(PM2_string)

// Result
console.log(PM2_obj)
console.log(PM2_obj.data)
console.log(PM2_obj.informations)
console.log(PM2_obj.name)
```

Comment: This would probably turn true|false booleans into strings too, right?

Comment: Sure @Andreas... This is a specific solution for a specific problem. In other words: a patch. Booleans, floating numbers, escaped double quotes in the original strings will still be problems (that was not requested here).

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your string is encoded in regular JavaScript or JSON5. JSON5 is a library which allows JSON to be defined in a similar way you would use it in regular JavaScript (without unnecessary `"`, etc.). Install the library and parse the string with `JSON5.parse()`. Reference: https://json5.org/

Answer (score 0):

the string is in JSON5 format and not regular JSON format. To parse a JSON5 string in JavaScript, you will need to use a library that supports the JSON5 format, like `json5`.

install:

```
npm install json5
```

```
import json5 from 'json5';
const str = "{data: 0, informations: 'hello', name: 'test'}";
const obj = json5.parse(str);
```

By the way, you could also use [Hjson](https://hjson.github.io/) to parse that string. [JSON5](https://json-5.com/json-vs-json5) is a more widely adopted format than Hjson, and has been around for longer. Hjson, while still relatively popular, can be a good choice for configuration files where human readability and ease of use are a priority.